# Expand row by column : Expand row by multiple columns and load different components according to the column clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am following below example to implement "expand row by column".

```
/* eslint max-len: 0 */
import React from 'react';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';

const products = [];

function addProducts(quantity) {
  const startId = products.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    const id = startId + i;
    if (i < 3) {
      products.push({
        id: id,
        name: 'Item name ' + id,
        price: 2100 + i,
        expand: [ {
          fieldA: 'test1',
          fieldB: (i + 1) * 99,
          fieldC: (i + 1) * Math.random() * 100,
          fieldD: '123eedd' + i
        }, {
          fieldA: 'test2',
          fieldB: i * 99,
          fieldC: i * Math.random() * 100,
          fieldD: '123eedd' + i
        } ]
      });
    } else {
      products.push({
        id: id,
        name: 'Item name ' + id,
        price: 2100 + i
      });
    }
  }
}
addProducts(5);

class BSTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.data) {
      return (
        <BootstrapTable data={ this.props.data }>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='fieldA' isKey={ true }>Field A</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='fieldB'>Field B</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='fieldC'>Field C</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='fieldD'>Field D</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>);
    } else {
      return (<p>?</p>);
    }
  }
}

export default class ExpandRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  isExpandableRow(row) {
    if (row.id < 3) return true;
    else return false;
  }

  expandComponent(row) {
    return (
      <BSTable data={ row.expand } />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const options = {
      expandRowBgColor: 'rgb(242, 255, 163)',
      expandBy: 'column'  // Currently, available value is row and column, default is row
    };
    return (
      <BootstrapTable data={ products }
        options={ options }
        expandableRow={ this.isExpandableRow }
        expandComponent={ this.expandComponent }
        search>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='id' isKey={ true }>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name' expandable={ false }>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price' expandable={ false }>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>
    );
  }
}
```

Questions:
I want to implement expand row on "multiple columns". For eg:

I would make 2 columns out of 3 to expand rows.

Product ID
Product Name
Product Price

Behavior I want is :

1.) When user clicks on "product id" column, I want to show some other BSTTableNew component like above (on expand row) but with columns "field A" & "field B" and some other functionality.

2.) When user clicks on "product name" column, I want to show BSTTable (on expand row) with similarly as above.

What changes I have to make in below code to load respective component class based upon the column I click to expand row with additional details?

I believe i have to make some changes in below code to load other components:

```
expandComponent(row) {

if( column === "productID") { //something of this sort I want
  return (
    <BSTableNew data={ row.expand } />
  );
}

if( column === "productName") {  //something of this sort I want
  return (
    <BSTable data={ row.expand } />
  );
}
}
```

How to achieve above?

Comment: @allenfang if you can help

Comment: About your second error, `join`is defined on `Array` objects. I'm almost sure that `cell` is a string

Comment: Share some code on https://codesandbox.io/ or share some pics to understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`react-bootstrap-table` is deprecated, you should use `react-bootstrap-table2`

---

If I correctly understood requirements, you want to expand row but the expanded content should be different, depending on column/cell clicked.

### 1st - expanded rows

Taking ['Expand Management'](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Row%20Expand&selectedStory=Expand%20Management&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) example as a base we can see how to control expanded rows using an array in the state. It's easy but we can't use `onExpand` handler as not column dependent. We can use `expanded` option:

```
expanded: this.state.expanded,
```

This array contains only expanded rows indexes.

### 2nd - what column clicked ?

Examples contains ['Column Event'](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Columns&selectedStory=Column%20Event&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) - `onClick` gets `column` param we need. This event must be defined in `columns`, f.e. sth like:

```
const columns = [{
  dataField: 'id',
  text: 'Product ID',
  events: {
    onClick: (e, column, columnIndex, row, rowIndex) => {
      console.log(row, column);
      const isRowExpanded = this.state.expanded.includes( row );
      this.setState( {
        column: 'id',
        expanded: isRowExpanded ? 
          this.state.expanded.filter(x => x !== row)
          : [...this.state.expanded, row]
      });
    }
  }
}, {
  dataField: 'name',
  text: 'Product Name',
  events: {
    onClick: (e, column, columnIndex, row,     rowIndex) => {
      console.log(row, column);
      const isRowExpanded =     this.state.expanded.includes( row );
      this.setState( {
        column: 'name',
        expanded: isRowExpanded ? 
          this.state.expanded.filter(x => x !== row)
          : [...this.state.expanded, row]
      });
    }
  }
}, {
  dataField: 'price',
  text: 'Product Price'
}];
```

This way we have both thing handled - expanded row and last clicked column.

### 3rd - display the appropriate component

We need only expanded renderer parametrization:

```
const expandRow = {
  renderer: row => {
    if (this.state.column==='id') {
      return (
        <ColumnIDClickedTable someParam={someData[row]} />
      )
    } else {
      return <ColumnNameClickedTable />
    }
  },
```

That should be all.
Adding condition for only first 3 rows expandable is an easy task.
All expanded rows will change the content on column change - only last click saved. Save column in indexed array if you need individual row behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a query, clicking on cells on the same row should not close the expanded row, rather it should just change the content. Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: @user1919581 this solution should work like you need or can be easy adapted